# Throwing Type error while importing PyARMViz package. How to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, apriori, python-visual

from PyARMViz import PyARMViz
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
from PyARMViz import PyARMViz

File "C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyARMViz_*init*_.py", line 14, in 
from PyARMViz.PyARMViz import adjacency_parallel_category_plot

File "C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyARMViz\PyARMViz.py", line 371, in 
def adjacency_graph_gephi(rules:List[Rule], output_path:str=None):

File "C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 261, in inner
return func(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 685, in **getitem**
params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)

File "C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 685, in 
params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)

File "C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 149, in _type_check
raise TypeError(f"{msg} Got {arg!r:.100}.")

TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module 'PyARMViz.Rule' from 'C:\Users\naveen-raj-b\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyARMViz\Rule.

Answer (score 3):

assuming you've downloaded the source code to your local machine

in the PyARMViz.py file,

change this  (line 5):

```
from PyARMViz import Rule
```

to this:

```
from PyARMViz.Rule import Rule
```

then rebuild using "pip install ."